# Does the sequence $\frac{1}{1-n}$ converge?

Tags: real-analysis

New to analysis here. I recognise this sequence converges to $0$, but surely it's unbounded since it's undefined at $n = 1$, which is a contradiction. Could someone just point out the problem in my thought process?

Thanks

Comment: A sequence, by definition, is a function defined on $\Bbb N$. You have not given us a sequence, so we can't talk about its convergence.

Comment: Well, you haven't said what the sequence is.  What is the range of values for $n$?  Doesn't make sense to include $n=1$ since the expression isn't even defined when $n=1$.

Comment: Moreover, "unbounded" and "undefined" are not the same. It is not correct to say that this *sequence* is unbounded, because it is not even a sequence to begin with!

Comment: Here, you have to start with $n=2$. The limit for $n\rightarrow\infty$ is $0$ , as you mentioned.

Comment: Note that if $n \to -\infty$, the sequence is positive and also convergence to $0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a sequence, it's not unbounded. It's just not defined when $n=1$. This sequence could reasonably be defined for $n\ge 2$. And so yes it is indeed convergent to $0$.

Answer (score 2):

Strict answer: The description

> $\frac1{1-n}$ for $n\in\Bbb N$

does not define a sequence. It defines something very sequence-like, but the fact that it's undefined for $n=1$ means it isn't a sequence. Until this is remedied, there is no point in going further.

Intuitive answer: The convergence of a sequence cares not about what happens for the first few terms (for *any* reasonable definition of "few").